# Getting R's scales::percent() function to evaluate 100% as greater than 20%

Tags: r

When I type `percent(100/100) > percent(20/100)`, I get `[1] FALSE`. How do I get it to evaluate as true because 100% is definitely greate than 20%?

Just to confirm that I'm actually trying to evaluate the right numbers

```
> percent(20/100)
[1] "20%"
> percent(100/100)
[1] "100%"
```

Thank you!

Comment: `percent` is for generating character labels, not numeric values. As a result `"100" < "20"` is `TRUE` when dealing with characters. You need to compare using the raw numbers *before* converting via `percent()`.

Answer (score 3):

`percent(20/100)` is of class "character"

```
library(scales)
class(percent(20/100))
#[1] "character"
```

Hence, when you are comparing them you are actually comparing

```
"20.0%" > "100.0%"
#[1] TRUE
```

which is `TRUE` because here it compares the first character "2" with "1" and `"2" > "1"` is `TRUE`.

I would suggest you compare the numbers before using `percent` on them.

```
(20/100) > (100/100)
#[1] FALSE
```